# What approaches for soundproofing for this situation?

Tags: audio-engineering

I am trying to learn soundproofing on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundproofing) (please let me know if there exists any other oninle tutorials).

> There are several basic approaches to reducing sound: increasing the distance between source and receiver, using noise barriers to reflect or absorb the energy of the sound waves, using damping structures such as sound baffles, or using active antinoise sound generators.

consider this situation, there is a noisy machine which generate lots types of noise in room A where I am not allowed to do anything, I am living in room B, where I am allowed to do something for soundproofing.

[image]

the approaches including increasing the distance, using active antinoise sound generators seems not to be suitable for my situation, so, noise barriers, damping structures are the approaches available, right? what I am mising? what esle I could use?

Answer (score 0):

"Noise" or sound level is just waves of air pressure. So anything to reduce air pressure. Noise level is reduced by increasing the distance from the source following the inverse square law (same sound intensity force but over a larger area). Sound baffling equipment work as well by just absorbing the sound waves instead of reflecting them around an enclosure. Ever notice a how a room seems "louder" after you take all the furniture out? The bare floor and walls reflect a lot more sound waves than furniture. So adding some carpet and soft chairs or wall hangings would help (or just straight up acoustic tiles). Check out anechoic chambers for extreme ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use heavy, lush carpeting, thick solid fabric for drapery, bulky furniture on rubber leg bases, and even heavy wallpapers. wear rubber sole shoes as a vibration barrier.

If your space is structurally connected to the other room, unfortunately, much of the base spectrum of noise will be transferred through the foundation or beams and walls.

You may also consider using an active noise canceling headset at the noisiest times.